# TestCafe: problem with specifying selector: span to grab text

Tags: testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I would like to grab the text from span but I have a problem with pointing this selector.

[image]

I tried defined it following:

1. `this.channelName = Selector('span[class="scheduler-header__service-name"]');`
   or
2. `this.channelName = Selector('div').find('#schedule').find('.scheduler-header').find('.scheduler-header__service-name')`

And I always received information:

`“Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.”`

Could somebody declare this selector for me?

Answer (score 3):

it was easy:)
this.channelName = Selector('.scheduler-header__service-name');

Answer (score 0):

If you run into the problem of writing a selector again, use the [Generate a Selector query](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404288/guides/intermediate-guides/visual-selector-debugger#generate-a-selector-query) function. It is available in TestCafe@2.4.0.